# Failed to read HTTP message: org.s.HttReadableException: Could not read document: Unrecognized token 'PUT': was expecting ('true', 'false' or 'null')

Tags: spring, rest, spring-data-jpa

I am implementing SPRING data JPA+ Oracle in spring STS... it is`sample application in postman i am getting response 200 for Get methods but for post and put Failed to read data from DB i guess and give below error -

> Failed to read HTTP message:
>   org.springframework.http.converter.HttpMessageNotReadableException:
>   Could not read document: Unrecognized token 'PUT': was expecting
>   ('true', 'false' or 'null')  at [Source:
>   java.io.PushbackInputStream@1f1076e7; line: 1, column: 5]; nested
>   exception is com.fasterxml.jackson.core.JsonParseException:
>   Unrecognized token 'PUT': was expecting ('true', 'false' or 'null') 
>   at [Source: java.io.PushbackInputStream@1f1076e7; line: 1, column: 5]

```
@Service
public class PersonService {
    @Autowired
    private PersonRepository personRepository;


    public Object findAll() {
        return personRepository.findAll();
    }

    public Person findById(Long id) {
        return personRepository.findOne(id);
    }

    public Person save(Person person) {
        return personRepository.save(person);
    }


    public Person delete(Person person) {
        personRepository.delete(person);
        return person;
    }

    public Person findByEmail(String email){ return null; }
}
```

Controller methods:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/all", method = RequestMethod.GET, consumes = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE, produces = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE)
public Hashtable<String, Person> gatAll() {
    return personService.getAll();
}

@RequestMapping(value = "/update/{id}", method = RequestMethod.PUT, produces = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE, consumes = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE)
@ResponseBody
public String updateUser(@RequestBody Person person, @PathVariable long id) {
    try {
        person.setId(id);
        personService.save(person);
    } catch (Exception ex) {
        return "Error in Updating the user : " + ex.toString();
    }

    return "User successfully Updated";
}
```

Answer (score 5):

The error could be due to the format of data you are giving to your controller. Your controller method is expecting JSON string.
For example in case of jQuery, JSON.stringify() gives you JSON string. 
So I would suggest you confirm this at the client side from where you're sending the data to this controller.

I had faced similar error while working on one of my projects. My client side was written in python which was supposed to send me the JSON string. So, I had to use dumps() and it worked.